# whats the best way to store the post in blogs

Tags: html, spring, jsp, blogs

I am trying to write a webapp, where one of the functionality is to exchange messages. I am trying to understand how to store these messages. I do not want to store it in DB. If i have to store in file, then how do i separate between messages.

Any links to some document would be greatly appreciated. I tried googling a lot but could not get hold of any reference

Comment: A DB would be the right tool here, it gives you many more advantages and is likely faster than reading and parsing a file. Anyways, you could store them in a semi-structured format, such as XML, YAML or JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about storing the messages in XML format, and use your webapp to load and parse those XML files into the message objects. Why do you not want to store the messages in the database? There are serious drawbacks to storing in the file system rather then the database (or even system memory).

Comment: XML is a very good solution. I reason i do not want to store in DB is, some of the web hosting companies provide very less DB space. So i thought it is better to architect in such a way that these messages are stored in file

Comment: Ahhh I understand... reading the messages from an XML file whenever you want to display or edit your messages could slow down your page loads when there are a lot of messages. You might want to think about storing new or recent conversations in the database and then moving them to XML when they are not frequented as often (but that involves keeping a retention cycle and more maintenance)

Answer (score 1):

A file system is a database, just not a relational database.
It's often faster than a relation database, but it has significantly less flexibility for indexing on multiple fields.

Parsing XML is gonna suck whether the XML comes from a database or a file.
Instead, you should do page caching to the file system of HTML, or HTML fragments.

Comment: Well i think again the issue with caching is, we need to go for a higher web hosting options, since it is going to require more memory and server resources.